# Error: Could not find or load main class weka.Run

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, weka, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to save some data in CSV format in HDFS. I run the following command in the terminal in ubuntu 11.10:

> ***java weka.Run .HDFSSaver -i ~/weka-3-7-12/data/iris.arff -dest /user/ubuntu/iris.csv -saver "weka.core.converters.CSVSaver -N"***

and I get the following error:

> ***Error: Could not find or load main class weka.Run***.

Can anyone help me with this? I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I am using weka-3-7-12 and Hadoop 2.6.0.

Comment: What is your CLASSPATH? If weka is not on your classpath then you need to use `java`'s `-cp` parameter

Comment: I have already exported the classpath and then ran this code

Comment: ok i have got it working but now i am getting a different error.

Comment: I run the same command above but now i get the following error:

java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

Comment: What's the full exception?

Comment: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
 at weka.core.converters.HDFSSaver.writeBatch(HDFSSaver.java:501)
 at weka.core.converters.DFSConverterUtils.runSaver(DFSConverterUtils.java:176)
 at weka.core.converters.HDFSSaver.run(HDFSSaver.java:529)
 at weka.Run.main(Run.java:329)

Comment: continued part: 

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1144)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:276)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:241)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1411)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1429)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)

Comment: at weka.core.converters.HDFSSaver.writeBatch(HDFSSaver.java:488)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:848)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:786)